# Automatically show the price and send mail to employee

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, dynamics-365

I don't know this is the place i can ask this type of question.

- I need to  Create a model driven app in power apps to manage
  employee onboarding and customer management.
- Managers should be
  able to add new stylists with their Name, age, ID Number etc.
- Receptionist should be able to save customer details, then add a slot
  for them and assign  to a stylist.
- Cost of service should be auto
  populated based on service selected in slot.
- Send notification to employee email when slot is assigned.

I have done first 3 points,But face issue in do last two points i have no idea about how do these things do.i reffer Microsoft learning section but i find only create canvas application

Can you help me to solve the last two points

Comment: can you provide more details on what a slot is and your data model?  For the final point I imagine you’ll need to implement a Power Automate flow triggered “when slot is assigned”

Comment: Slot means time and date, similar to make an appointment

Comment: I completed the task.

Answer (score -1):

I completed the task

First,To display the Service and associated cost i add a form input which you can see in the form editing section (Display Section)

Second,I created a cloud flow and select the slot table and create a flow whenever new row is added and set sub flow is set an Send email(v2) and set the destination

Thank you